# creating visualizations from logs pushed in to redis without elk

Tags: redis, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

I am new to elk stack and till now I am able to create visualization and now I want to move elk stack into cloud and on local machine. I am trying to create visualization of logs I have sent from filebeat to redis is there any tool or plugin of kibana it self to create visualization directly from redis **(ie. not pushing logs in elk stack)**.

Comment: Kiabana is a visualization tool on top of ES. You will have to send data to ES.